# For the non-IT savvy GIS person (not great w/ Linux & Apache) could someone suggest how to set up PostgreSQL, Geoserver, and ISS/Apache?

Tags: postgis, geoserver, postgresql, apache

I've heard of GeoCommon as being an easy GIS solution, but I'd like to host the data locally for internal users.  I know of a group called Open Geosuite - but the ongoing maintenance is something I'd like to avoid since I can do pretty well with maintenance and content management & web site publishing after the initial set-up.

Does anyone know of an out-of-the-box solution or a group/company that can help with initial set up for these types of map service stacks?

Thanks for any advice you can give for a noob!

Comment: What is your goal? How the users will consume data? You can maintain but you can't setup? Have you really tried the manual setup? If so, Explain your difficulties and the points that you have trouble, be more specific.

Comment: You can download the community edition of OpenGeo Suite for free and there's no maintenance costs involved.  http://opengeo.org/technology/suite/  It's not that much different than the so-called enterprise edition.  Otherwise, jump right in and install the PostgreSQL/PostGIS and GeoServer binaries by themselves.  The installation and configuration is covered pretty well in the documentation.

Comment: portable gis is pretty good too v3 is just released - due to file size and hosting geoserver is out - but if enough request it it will be considered to be put back in - http://www.archaeogeek.com/blog/2012/09/12/portable-gis-v3-released/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://opengeo.org/

Open Geo Suite is probably what you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

Similarly to @Vadim's answer, you could try playing with OSGeo Live, which is a Linux live DVD with everything OS GIS set up for you, then from there you can set up the components you're interested in.

Answer (score 1):

Installing the stack is not that difficult. I'm a noob and have done it. In Windows it's trivial. Install postgresql with "stackbuilder" PostgreSQL Windows stack installer. It will ask about installing a PostGIS instance or allow you to do so. Install PGAdminIII, you can connect QGIS to it as well, load data, and you're off to the races.

The problem is the client which mostly seem a pain for us noobs. Try Drupal with OpenLayers for that. Cartaro in Drupal will do what your looking for once it gets to alpha.

The other option was OpenGeo, try it on Ubuntu 12.04 in virtual box, if you're an enterprise you might have to pay.